# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser backhground no longer transparent in

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

We've seen an issue in our software that uses CefSharp to display web browser based content on WPF views, that the background has gone from being transparent (in versions upto 81.3.100) to white (83.4.20).

It's easily reproducible. Create a Window with a lightblue background and a `cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser`:

```
<Window x:Class="CefSharpIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="200"
        Width="840"
        Background="LightBlue">
    <Grid>
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="BrowserView" Margin="10" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And then in code load some HTML that displays text:

```
using CefSharp;
using System.Windows;

namespace CefSharpIssue
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BrowserView.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                    BrowserView.LoadHtml(
                        "<html><body><h1>"
                            + $"CefSharpVersion {Cef.ChromiumVersion}<br>"
                            + $"CefVersion {Cef.CefVersion}<br>"
                            + $"CefSharpVersion {Cef.CefSharpVersion}"
                        + "</h1></body></html>");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

CefSharp 83.4.20:
[image: CefSharp 83.4.20]

CefSharp 81.3.100:
[image: CefSharp 81.3.100]

CefSharp 79.1.360:
[image: CefSharp 79.1.360]

CefSharp 75.1.143:
[image: CefSharp 75.1.143]

(it worked with a transparent background for as long as we've been using it. I just wanted to confirm it's change introduced in 83.4.20, not a bug that existed in one previous version)

I've tried setting the [CefSettings.BackgroundColor](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefSettingsBase_BackgroundColor.htm) and the [BrowserSettings.BackgroundColor](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/P_CefSharp_BrowserSettings_BackgroundColor.htm) with no results.

Is this a bug in CefSharp, or some change to functionality that I can't find in the release notes, and it so, does anyone have a workaround (other than sticking with 81.3.100 which I don't really want to do)?

Comment: As per the known issues section of the release notes https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v83.4.20 there is an upstream bug. https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2938/osr-transparent-background-broken-since

Comment: @amaitland thanks, I completely missed that.

Comment: From what I understand the problem has been resolved with GPU acceleration enabled, you can try out a CI build https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#releases-1